# Input type=file make the form empty in firefox

Tags: php, html, firefox

I am doing a simple form in html to upload an image
In chrome is working properly but in firefox for some reason the variable `$_POS`T is empty

This is my form

```
<form action="do_upload.php" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
        <fieldset>
            <p>Select a section</p>
                <select name="section" required>
                    <option value="">Please Select</option>
                    <option value="0">Announcements</option>
                    <option value="1">Circulars</option>
                    <option value="2">Corportate Governance</option>
                    <option value="3">Financial Report</option>
                </select>
            <p>Date</p>
                <input type="text" name="date" required>
            <p>Title</p>
                <input type="text" name="title" required>
            <p>Search your file</p>
                <input type="file" name="pdf" required>
            <div class="sep"></div>
            <button type="submit">Do it!</button>
        </fieldset>
    </form>
```

And in my file do_upload.php I have only this:

```
print_r($_POST);
```

Even I fill all the form I always get the array `$_POST` empty

I know that to get the file I need to use the global `$_FILE`, I just want to know why firefox show me an empty array when I use input type file.

Any idea? I should be able to get this:

```
Array ( [section] => 3 [date] => 07/05/2016 [title] => 123 )
```

Comment: check post_max_size in your ini file, if file exceeds the size , then $_POST will always be empty

Comment: do you have anything doing a redirect before the submit reaches `do_upload.php`?

Comment: also check upload_max_filesize

Comment: Whenever you do a file upload, the files get populated in the $_FILES global variable, and the other fields get populated in the $_POST global variable.

Comment: hey my problem is not getting the file, I know how to get it. I need to know why in firefox the array post become empty if I add a file... will try with an smaller file

Comment: yes, is a problem of the size of the file... thank you!!

Answer (score 1):

If your input type is `file` you have to access the value on serverside via `$_FILES["pdf"]`.

**Description**

An associative array of items uploaded to the current script via the HTTP POST method. The structure of this array is outlined in the POST method uploads section.

See: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.files.php

And: http://php.net/manual/en/features.file-upload.post-method.php

Comment: hey my problem is not getting the file, I know how to get it. I need to know why in firefox the array post become empty if I add a file

Answer (score 0):

Whenever you do a file upload, the files get populated in the $_FILES global variable, and the other fields get populated in the $_POST global variable.

```
echo $_FILES['pdf']['name'];
```

Comment: he actually needs `echo $_FILES['pdf']['tmp_name'];`

Comment: I know how to get the file, I dont know why array $_POST become empty in firefox